# Cannot AzureBlobStorage initialization in Bot Framework 4.9

Tags: botframework, azure-storage

I am implementing "AzureBlobStorage" by referencing "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure", but when I initialize I get an error with "CloudStorageAccount".

> Error CS7069  Reference to type 'CloudStorageAccount' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common', but it could not be found QBotSolution

[image: Startup.cs image:]

Solution Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio can't determine which package you're trying to use. If you're just looking to do traditional bot state management, you should remove these packages:

1. Azure.Storage.Blobs
2. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
3. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob
4. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common

For bot Blob storage, you should only need `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure`, so be sure to include `using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure;` at the top of whatever file you're trying to use this in.

Here's a few good references:

- [State Management Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/3cfb7eec6a11f653203781c652245a6288d6286e/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/42.scaleout)
- [Write Directly to Storage - Using Blob Storage Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-blob-storage)
- [State Management Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)